# Getting UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning despite several `try`-`catch` blocks

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I'm using a 3rd party module that wraps around their API. I have the following code:

```js
const api = require('3rdpartyapi');

 async function callAPI(params) {
  try {
    let result = await api.call(params);
    return result;
  }
  catch(err) {
    throw err;  //will handle in other function
  }
 }
 
 async function doSomething() {
  try {
    //...do stuff
    let result = await callAPI({a:2,b:7});
    console.log(result);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.error('oh no!', err);
  }
}
```

Despite both `try`-`catch` blocks, the 3rd party API, when it losses connection to homebase (happens quite frequently :( ), blows up with:

```
(node:13128) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: request to https://www.example.com failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
```

Followed by:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

How come none of my `try`-`catch` catch this? What exactly is unhandled, and how to actually handle this?

Comment: If you're sure you are handling the error you throw in the other function, then, is there some unhandled promise rejection within the 3rd party api? Can you trace the api.call() function and see if you find any unhandled promise?

Comment: @BryanOliveira no, I don't have the code - but the question remains: how can it be unhandled inside a different function? Shouldn't one of my catch blocks catch it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point is the await only converts "first layer" rejection into error, however the promise can have promise inside, and their library may fail to catch the rejection inside. I have made a proof of concept 3rdpartyapi which can trigger the behavior you see:

```js
(async function () {

// mock 3rdpartyapi
var api = {
    call: async function(){
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // why wrap a promise here? but i don't know
            new Promise((innerResolve, innerReject) => {
                innerReject('very sad'); // unfortunately this inner promise fail
                reject('this sadness can bubble up');
            })
        })
    }
};

// your original code
async function callAPI(params) {
    try {
        let result = await api.call(params);
        return result;
    } catch (err) {
        throw err; //will handle in other function
    }
}

async function doSomething() {
    try {
        //...do stuff
        let result = await callAPI({
            a: 2,
            b: 7
        });
        console.log(result);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('oh no!', err);
    }
}

doSomething();

})();
```

Output:

```
$ node start.js
oh no! this sadness can bubble up
(node:17688) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: very sad
(node:17688) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:17688) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Ouch! Is there any way I can still catch that inner rejection? At the end of the day, I need to prevent a crash and report an error to my client.

Comment: And BTW, in you sample code, the "oh no!" was printed out, i.e. the error was captured on a higher level. In my case, I never see it.

Comment: you can see [unhandledRejection event](https://thecodebarbarian.com/unhandled-promise-rejections-in-node.js.html). for your case, it might be that the 3rd party library has `return` on the innerReject line, so that the `reject` for first layer is never called

Comment: Thanks for the enlightening resource. The guy there claims all you have to do to suppress an unhandledException event is to add a `catch`. Since the 2 I have don't work, am I to conclude that there's nothing else I can do until the 3rd party fixes their code to handle their internal issue?

Comment: yeah since you can't add the catch the inner rejection because you can't add `catch` to the inner promise. maybe send them an email/ticket regarding this discovery too to facilitate fix.

Comment: Already did. They said they'd give me access to their git and I should find the bug and open a PR. Wasn't aware I was working for them now... :). At any rate, thanks for the assist, the demo and the link.